# Button not aligning correctly as responsive should

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, responsive

in the footer widget on a wordpress page, the join now button is going out of alignment when looking with responsive viewing on mobile.  the code is: join now

how do i fix this so it lines up correctly?  it's at https://time2track.com/ in the footer

I have looked at the code but do not know how to make this line up correctly

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] and [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick look at your website, it seems like you are using "float: left" on the div that contains 2 links before your "Join Now" button. Just use "clear: both" on the div after the floated div. In your case on div with id "custom_html-2".
Also, it would be beneficial to read this article: [All about floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#:%7E:text=Clearing%20the%20Float,itself%20down%20past%20the%20float.)

Please provide code sample next time, as that would be the easiest way to seek answers.